# Cant install Jekyll on windows..certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, jekyll

Trying to install Ruby and Jekyll on windows following

http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/

Everything was going great until I try to install jekll... then I get the following error

```
$ gem install jekyll
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'jekyll' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an error due to SSL certificates and you would need to manually specify a SSL certificate for ruby. Here are the exact steps to fix this issue:

- Download the [cacert.pem](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) file and save this file to C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem
- Open System in Control Panel Go to
- Advanced System Settings Click on Environment Variables Define a new
- System Variable with SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem
- Close and reopen your command prompt for allowing the changes to take place

Screenshots and more details are available in this article - 
[Fixing SSL_connect error while installing Ruby Gems on Windows](http://codingtips.kanishkkunal.in/ssl-error-ruby-gems-windows/)